# How to capture HTTP Traffic if the application uses Automatic Configuration Script?

Tags: http-proxy

I am testing an application that requires "Automatic configuration script" to be configured in web browser.

How can i intercept HTTP traffic in such case. I am aware of temper data add-on but is there a way to configure HTTP proxy (such as burp/paros) in such case?

Comment: HTTP only or is it HTTPS?

Comment: It is HTTP only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Using Upstream proxy in burp suite this can be accomplished. Burp will forward the traffic to the proxy URL and will receive the response.